# Windows Authentication fails in Application but succeeds in dedicated Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-10, windows-authentication

I am trying to configure 2 ASP.NET projects in IIS where one inherits from the other.

The base uses anonymous authentication and the derived uses windows authentication.

So the web.config can be inherited, I would like the derived to be an application inside the base site. I have configured this but keep receiving a 401.1 error when accessing the application that is the derived.

To test my configuration I created a brand new website, pointing to the same physical folder, in the same application pool and configured windows authentication the same as the virtual directory. Accessing this works fine.

I have 2 folders:

```
Base
Derived
```

In IIS I have configured (causes the 401):

```
Base (Site, Anon + Windows (also tried just anon))
|- Derived (Application, Windows)
```

and (works fine):

```
Derived (Site, Windows)
```

I created the separate derived site to prove to myself it wasn't permissions related to that folder or something in the web.config of the derived site causing problems.

There are no authorization or authentication elements in the base web.config.

The FDQN for both sites is present in my HOSTS file and the PC is in domain.

Is there something special about applications inside sites that makes what I am trying to achieve impossible?

Answer (score 0):

A 401 response is the normal first step for Windows Authentication. The browser is probably giving you a pop-up window to enter your credentials. If you enter your Windows credentials and it works, then everything on the server is configured correctly.

To have the browser automatically send your credentials, you need to configure the client computer. For Chrome and IE, the website needs to be added to the Trusted Sites in Internet Options. Firefox has [its own settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Integrated_authentication).

Comment: I'm not accessing this through a browser. However, the mechanism I am using works fine for the separate site but fails for the sub application. There is something different about how the sub application is behaving.

Comment: The difference (according to your description) is Windows Authentication, no? Windows Authentication will send a 401. You are expected to resend the request with the proper credentials. See [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mist/2018/02/14/windows-authentication-http-request-flow-in-iis/) for details. How are you accessing the web site then?

Comment: My apologies, I have updated my question to (hopefully) make it clearer. I am testing this via the query designer in VS when designing an SSRS dataset.

Comment: How are you making an HTTP request in the query designer?

Comment: Turned out to be Loopback protection. I have no idea why it worked for the separate site because that should have failed too. Thanks for your help.